# onHotEncoding and lists in a pandas dataFrame

Tags: list, pandas, dataframe, multiple-columns, one-hot-encoding

I have a pandas dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd    
d={'col1':[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]],'col2':[[7,8,9],[10,11,12]]}
df=pd.DataFrame(d)
```

which results in:

[image: result of comman above]

however I want to implement a onHotEncoder, which will treat each list with the cells of the dataFrame as a *string*, and I want it to treat each *value* independently.

How would I implement this? My actual dataFrame contains lists of 500 items, and has 4000 unique values.

Comment: What is desired output from input?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can use [`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) for creating `Series`, then cast `list` to `string` by [`astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.astype.html), remove `[]` by [`strip`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.strip.html) and last call [`get_dummies`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.get_dummies.html):

```
df = df.stack().astype(str).str.strip('[]').str.get_dummies(sep=', ')
print (df)
        1  10  11  12  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9
0 col1  1   0   0   0  1  1  0  0  0  0  0  0
  col2  0   0   0   0  0  0  0  0  0  1  1  1
1 col1  0   0   0   0  0  0  1  1  1  0  0  0
  col2  0   1   1   1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
```

One column only:

```
df = df['col1'].astype(str).str.strip('[]').str.get_dummies(sep=', ') 
print (df)
   1  2  3  4  5  6
0  1  1  1  0  0  0
1  0  0  0  1  1  1
```

Comment: thanks that works, but to add to my question, how could I apply this to one column only?

Comment: you my friend, are a genius!

Comment: Super, I am really really happy I can help you! Good luck!